# Installing app to managed profile

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-managed-profile

I am playing around with the [BasicManagedProfile](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-BasicManagedProfile) sample and want to install a custom app to only the managed profile.  I can easily go to the play store, download, and install an app and it will only appear in the apps of the work profile.

However, using the standard Intent way to install an apk from the device does not seem to work.

```
    final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSTALL_PACKAGE);
    intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(APK_LOC)), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_NOT_UNKNOWN_SOURCE, true);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INSTALLER_PACKAGE_NAME, getPackageName());
    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_INSTALL, null);
```

Like normal, if the "Install from unknown sources" security setting isn't enabled, a dialog will pop up that sends you to the Settings app to enable it.  However, in a managed profile app, this dialog *always pops up* regardless of whether or not that security setting is checked.  It seems the settings are not reflected in a managed profile (which makes sense because it's an entirely separate settings database).

I have tried opening the Settings app directly, but it's still the same.  It just goes to the standards Settings app and not a Managed Profile settings app.

Is there a way to change this security setting for a managed profile or install an app from the profile owner app? Since my app is the profile owner it seems this should be allowed.  It's easily possible for system applications, but third party apps will not work with the `DevicePolicyManager#enableSystemApp()` method.

EDIT:

I have also tried installing from a Manage Profile Gmail app.  Same thing.  It does not seem possible to install apps outside the Google Play store in a managed profile.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Google has restricted the direct installation of .apk files in the managed profile.

The unusual behavior of the alert box saying the user to go to settings and enable the "install from unknown sources" even though it is enable is considered as an issue. See the Google issues page [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=79728) .

> Is there a way to change this security setting for a managed profile
>   or install an app from the profile owner app?

Currently there is no API or work arounds to install an .apk file in the managed profile. But for testing you can try through adb

```
 adb install appname.apk
```

This command would install the application in both the personal and the managed profile. Hope this helps you!

Comment: Hi Sarangan,can we use this feature to enable an application in both work profile and personal profile?

Comment: can confirm, that even that this is described on https://developer.android.com/work/managed-profiles, it doesn't work on my 8.1 device. App is installed in private space only

Comment: `adb install appname.apk` will only install it on my personal profile. I think this answer may be outdated.

Comment: It works for me on Android 13 if the app was not previously installed on the device.

Answer (score 1):

Go to edit the configuration in Android Studio as shown below in the image and then **click check Install for all users to install app for Work Profile and Normal Admin** similarly uncheck for Normal install.
[image]